# Realtime (reactivity) issue Vue js 3 and Supabase

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, supabase

I have an issue with reactivity in my component created using Vue js 3 and Supabase, input and fetching is working, "Realtime" is turned on in table settings. I have an input and "ul" to create and show "brands", input is working just fine, data is added to Supabase, but "ul" is not reactive, I have to refresh page to see added data, I have done same thing using Firestore and it worked fine.

```
<template>
  <div class="overview">
        <input type="text" v-model="brandname" @keyup.enter="saveBrand()">
    <ul v-for="brand in brands">
      <li>{{ brand.brandname }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue';
import supabase from '../supabaseClient';

export default {
  name: 'Overview',
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  setup() {
    const brands = ref([]);
    const brand = ref("");
    const brandname = ref("");
    const errorMessage = ref("");

    onMounted(() => {
      onSnapshot(dataBase, (snapshot) => {
        products.value = [];
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          products.value.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
        });
      });
    });

    const saveBrand = async () => {
      try {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
          .from('brands')
          .insert([
            {
              brandname: brandname.value,
            },
          ]);

        if (error) {
          errorMessage.value = 'Error storing data: ' + error.message;
        } else {
          console.log('Data stored successfully:', data);
          brandname.value = ''; // Clear the input field
        }
      } catch (error) {
        errorMessage.value = 'Error: ' + error.message;
      }
    };

    const fetchBrands = async () => {
      try {
        const { data, error } = await supabase.from('brands').select('brandname');

        if (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        } else {
          brands.value = data;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error.message);
      }
    };


    onMounted(() => {
      fetchBrands();
    });

    return {
      brands,
      brand,
      brandname,
      saveBrand,
      errorMessage
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: onSnapshot is the remnant of firestore, isn't it? Consider moving it to a separate snippet, as it's misleading. You're fetching once with supabase, so it's obviously not subscribed to changes. Should be like that, I suppose https://supabase.com/docs/guides/realtime/postgres-changes#listening-to-multiple-changes

Comment: Yeah, we would need the definition of `onSnapshot` in order to see what might be the cause.

Comment: I mistakenly left 'onSnapshot' from another function after deleting that function, and I forgot to remove it from 'onMounted'. However, below you can see the 'onMounted' that corresponds to Supabase.